# Create external table using Polybase on-premise error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, polybase

I'm trying to create an external table in SQL Server 2019 on premise ( Polybase has been installed and all services are up and running [Instance and 2 services for polybase] , Hadoop configuration = 7).

I want to feed the external table with multiple ".csv" or ".txt" files , for this example, Ill use 1 ".csv" file.

I've the lattest

1. OBCD Driver for "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"
2. "SQL Server® 2019 for Microsoft® Windows Latest Cumulative Update"

My first step was creating the EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE in my Database where Polybase is emabled using the code below:

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyODBC
WITH 
( 
    LOCATION = 'odbc://localhost',
    CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=C:\Historical\Event\',
    PUSHDOWN = OFF
);
```

Second, I've created the script to CREATE the EXTERNAL TABLE using dynamic SQL based on variables ( @TableName,@FolderPath variable values can change at any time).

Please see my script below:

```
DECLARE
    @TableName VARCHAR(15) = 'BRAO',
    @FolderPath VARCHAR(500) = 'BRAO\BRAO_EVEN0000_20220101.csv',
    @DataSourceName VARCHAR(20) ='MyODBC',
    @SQLScript NVARCHAR(MAX) =''


SET @SQLScript =N'

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
    *
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE
        object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[Gold' + @TableName + ']'')
        AND type in (N''U'')
)
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Gold' + @TableName + ']  

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[Gold' + @TableName + ']
(
    [Column1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Column2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](255) NULL

)
    
WITH (DATA_SOURCE =' + @DataSourceName + ',LOCATION = ''' + @FolderPath +  ''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLScript
```

When I run my script above, I get the following error:

> Msg 105121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> 105121;The specified LOCATION string 'BRAO\BRAO_EVEN0000_20220101.csv' could not be parsed. A 1-part identifier was found. Expected 2.

Comment: add backslash to the location in the beginning. `\BRAO\BRAO_EVEN0000_20220101.csv`

Comment: @VenkataramanR I did that, now the error changed to be almost identical but without the "Identifier not found". Not it only say :   "The specified LOCATION string '\BRAO\BRAO_EVEN0000_20220101.csv' could not be parsed."

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the following page? It loads a .csv file but the location is only a single folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118102/polybase-load-csv-file-that-contains-text-column-w.html